# Use -unsetDefault to remove NOT NULL constraints with ogr/gdal

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, feature-class, null

I have a feature class in a gdb that I wanted to export to a gpkg using `ogr2ogr`. This feature class has some null values that I want to retain and by default, there is a [`Not Nullable` constraint when using this ogr method.](https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc53_ogr_notnull_default.html) When I try to run, the following I get a  `NOT NULL constraint failed` error.

```
 ogr2ogr -f GPKG "C:\MyDir\MyGPKP.gpkg" "C:\MyDir\MyGDB.gdb" my_feature
```

I was able to use the -forceNullable to get this to work:

```
 ogr2ogr -f GPKG "C:\MyDir\MyGPKP.gpkg" "C:\MyDir\MyGDB.gdb" my_feature -forceNullable
```

But I am concerned this might cause data corruption down the line somewhere. I would prefer to use the -unsetDefault method to remove the constraint, but I still get the same error as above (  `NOT NULL constraint failed` error) when I run the below:

```
 ogr2ogr -f GPKG "C:\MyDir\MyGPKP.gpkg" "C:\MyDir\MyGDB.gdb" my_feature -unsetDefault
```

Is there a parameter or something I am missing that must be included (or a certain order or place I add the tag)? I can't seem to find a documented example of how to apply this method.

Comment: The switch in ogr2ogr means "Do not propagate not-nullable constraints to target layer if they exist in source layer." So if you have the constraint in the source .gdb and you get the "NOT NULL constraint failed" it should actually never happen if the source data are valid.  Instead of finding workarounds I would try to find the reason for the failure. Where do those nulls come?